# Can we integrate Oracle RECORD TYPE with java Callable statement?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Is it true that RECORD type is not compatible with JDBC? the driver am using is OJDBC6.jar

Java Code:

```
dbStrategy.openConnection();
        WrappedConnectionJDK6 wrapped = (WrappedConnectionJDK6) dbStrategy.getConnection();
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) wrapped.getUnderlyingConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = oracleConnection.prepareCall("{call XXX_Info_Utl_Pkg.get_order_admin(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(orderNumber));
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "XXX_INFO_UTL_PKG.SEAGRS_ORDER_REC");
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

And Oracle Code:

```
PROCEDURE get_order_admin(
            p_order_num_in IN NUMBER,
            p_order_admin_out OUT XXX_info_utl_pkg.seagrs_order_rec,
            p_error_code_out OUT PLS_INTEGER,
            p_error_msg_out OUT VARCHAR2,
            p_ret_status_out OUT PLS_INTEGER);


TYPE seagrs_order_rec
IS
    record
    (
        order_admin        VARCHAR2(10),
        contact_name       VARCHAR2(50),
        contact_email_addr VARCHAR2(100),
        contact_phone_num  VARCHAR2(30));
```

The error am facing here is -

> Exception : invalid name pattern: XXX_INFO_UTL_PKG.SEAGRS_ORDER_REC

Comment: Can you post full error stack?

Comment: 14:53:47,546 ERROR [com.commands.RecRetOrderAdminInfoCmd] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) EXCEPTION OCCURED ::Method Name : execute, Exception : invalid name pattern: XXX_INFO_UTL_PKG.XXX_ORDER_REC
14:53:47,562 ERROR [com.daos.ReceivingServiceDAO] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) EXCEPTION OCCURED : ReceivingServiceDAO, Method Name : getOrderAdminInfo

Comment: Your `seagrs_order_rec` is of what `type`? `Array or Object or table`?

Comment: TYPE seagrs_order_rec IS  record TYPE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Record Type is not compatible with JDBC drivers:

> It is not feasible for Oracle JDBC drivers to support calling
>   arguments or return values of the PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or table
>   with non-scalar element types. However, Oracle JDBC drivers support
>   PL/SQL index-by table of scalar element types.

[READ THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/apxref.htm)

Answer (score 6):

While you cannot use JDBC directly to fetch your PL/SQL RECORD type, you can write an anonymous PL/SQL block and return the record into a local variable, which you can then decompose in its individual attributes as follows:

```
DECLARE
    rec XXX_info_utl_pkg.seagrs_order_rec;
BEGIN
    get_order_admin(?, rec, ?, ?, ?);
    ? := rec.order_admin;
    ? := rec.contact_name;
    ? := rec.contact_email_addr;
    ? := rec.contact_phone_num;
END;
```

You can now use the following JDBC code to call the procedure:

```
try (CallableStatement s = con.prepareCall(" ... previous PL/SQL block ...")) {
    s.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(orderNumber));

    // Ordinary out parameters
    s.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMBER);
    s.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(4, Types.NUMBER);

    // Out parameters from your decomposed record
    s.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);

    s.execute();
    // Now, retrieve all the out parameters
}
```

[I have recently blogged about this technique more in detail](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/). The blog post also contains instructions about how you could automatically generate the anonymous PL/SQL blocks for all functions / procedures, that have record IN/OUT parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way using STRUCT type if you do not prefer to use direct pl/sql block inside your java code.

for example in your above code change type from array to struct:-

```
dbStrategy.openConnection();
        WrappedConnectionJDK6 wrapped = (WrappedConnectionJDK6) dbStrategy.getConnection();
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) wrapped.getUnderlyingConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = oracleConnection.prepareCall("{call XXX_Info_Utl_Pkg.get_order_admin(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(orderNumber));
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.STRUCT, "XXX_INFO_UTL_PKG.SEAGRS_ORDER_REC");
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```